# download file and crash app

Tags: android, crash, android-4.4-kitkat

my app downloaded file with this :

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
public static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS = 8344;
public DownloadService() {
    super("DownloadService");
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String urlToDownload = intent.getStringExtra("url");
    String fileToStore= intent.getStringExtra("file");
    ResultReceiver receiver = (ResultReceiver) intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/SingingStudio/"+fileToStore+".zip");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
            resultData.putInt("progress" ,(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
    resultData.putInt("progress" ,100);
    receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
}
}
```

my app work in any device properly . but in all kitkat version of android for example xperia z4 and too galaxy grande 4.2.2
when file downloaded . if i go to any activity app is crash .
but if it download file with DownloadManager app is not crash .

why ?

Comment: `if i go to any activity app is crash`. What has going to an activity to to with the code you posted?

Comment: The directory `SingingStudio` exists before you execute this code?

Comment: yes . i create SingingStudio in oncreate

Comment: logCat error is: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: app downloading music with above class and for play music i need go to new intent .